# How do I fix `tf.profiler.experimental.start` WARNING?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorboard

I'm trying to understand tensorboard graphs following a [tf tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/tensorboard/graphs#conceptual_graph), which gives this code

```
tf.summary.trace_on(graph=True, profiler=True)
```

Each time I ran it, I got this warning

```
WARNING:tensorflow:From /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/summary_ops_v2.py:1263: start (from tensorflow.python.eager.profiler) is deprecated and will be removed after 2020-07-01.
Instructions for updating:
use `tf.profiler.experimental.start` instead.
```

How do I fix it?

Comment: Please use tf.get_logger().setLevel('ERROR') to suppress the warning after importing tensorflow as tf.

Comment: @TensorflowSupport Thank you. It works! Do you consider moving it to answer?